# Django python manage.py runserver returns attribute error instead of launching the virtual server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, vagrant

I reviewed these lines many times and searched over the website to find a similar issue, but I just can't figure out what I missed to generate the error

**urls.py - profiles_api**

```py
from django.urls import path
from profiles_api import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_View()),
]
```

views.py - profiles_api

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """test API View"""

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """Returns a list of APIView features"""
        an_apiview = [
            'Uses HTTP methods as function (get, post, patch, put, delete)',
            'Is similar to a traditional Django View',
            'Gives you the most control over your application logic',
            'Is mapped manually to URLs',
        ]

        return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})
```

**urls.py - profiles_project**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('profiles_api.urls'))
]
```

**Exception:**

> (env) vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
>
> ....
>
> path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_View()),
>
> AttributeError: type object 'HelloApiView' has no attribute 'as_View'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says there's no attribute as_View. The problem is with V in upper case. There should be `as_view()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's [typo](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets) ? `as_view()` not <s>`as_View()`</s>